# Problems with Entity validation with Hibernate Validator

Tags: hibernate, jpa, gradle, jakarta-ee, hibernate-validator

I tried to activate automated entity validation via Hibernate Validator. Therefore, I added the following dependencies to my Gradle build file:

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:7.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-cdi:7.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:7.0.1.Final'
implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.el:4.0.1'
```

When starting my application, while builing the session factory, the following error is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.validation.ValidatorFactory
```

I was able to debug myself through the Hibernate implementation exactly to the point where the exception comes from. Since I use the latest implementation of the Hibernate Validator, I am aware that the namespace has been moved from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. However, this piece of code in `BeanValidationIntegrator.java` seems to load a class that depends on some old (?) validation package(s) from `javax.*`:

```
// see if the Bean Validation API is available on the classpath
    if ( isBeanValidationApiAvailable( classLoaderService ) ) {
        // and if so, call out to the TypeSafeActivator
        try {
            final Class typeSafeActivatorClass = loadTypeSafeActivatorClass( classLoaderService );
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            final Method activateMethod = typeSafeActivatorClass.getMethod( ACTIVATE_METHOD_NAME, ActivationContext.class );
```

I was able to let my IDE show me the source code of the loaded `typeSafeActivatorClass` and saw that it really depends on `javax.validation.*`.

So I added the required dependency to my build file (`javax.validation:validation-api:2.0.1.Final`) and to test whether validation would work now, I added the following property to my Hibernate config:

```
jakarta.persistence.validation.mode=callback
```

Unfortunately, I get an error that no bean validation implementation is available.

Any help would be appreciated so much!!

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the [release announcement of Hibernate 5.5.0](https://in.relation.to/2021/06/02/hibernate-orm-550-final-release/), you have to use the hibernate artifacts with a `-jakarta` artifact id suffix. Seems you are not doing that.